# Searching and sorting by a float field with thinking sphinx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx

I'm using thinking sphinx to for search on a rails app.  I have a float field called 'height'.  I need to be able to search this field for exact values (i.e. exactly 6.0, not 6.5). I also need to be able to sort on the field.

What I have so far:

```
indexes height, :sortable => true
```

Problem:
    doesn't sort properly, returns 6.0 and 6.5 if I search for '6'

Answer (score 3):

If you're dealing with float values, it's best to have them as an attribute instead of a field:

```
define_index do
  # ... other fields

  has height
end
```

Attributes are sortable by default (indeed, if you add :sortable to a field, all it is doing is creating an attribute under the hood of Thinking Sphinx), so this should allow you to sort.

Of course, this doesn't allow you to *search* for the height, though, so you'll need a field as well:

```
define_index do
  # ... other fields
  indexes height, :as => :height_field

  has height
end
```

I've given the field an alias, because you can't have fields and attributes named the same thing.

Given all that, you're searching on a float, and to Sphinx, all fields are strings. It reads 6.5 as two words - 6 and 5, separated by a full stop/period. So I wouldn't expect that side of things to work out elegantly, unfortunately.