# Thinking Sphinx - filtering by negative attribute doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

Thinking Sphinx doesn't find any records with negative column values. In my case, the column is "site_id", which can contain -1 (we use -1 instead of NULL). My index looks like the sample below (with the four different examples that I tried separately):

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :incident, with: :active_record, delta: ThinkingSphinx::Deltas::ResqueDelta do
  indexes site_id
  # indexes site_id, type: :float
  # has site_id
  # has site_id, type: :float
end
```

The solutions I tried are according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24500046/1772) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/880307/1772), but it doesn't work for me. My Sphinx version doesn't support the == operator for floats. I get:

> sphinxql: only >=, <=, and BETWEEN floating-point filter types are supported in this version

Upgrading Sphinx is not really an option. What else can be done to make this work?

Comment: When you are changing the type of the attribute, are you regenerating the index? The sphinx index will need recreating (the ts:rebuild task?) - also did you read answer mentioning need to change the filter the correct type too.

Comment: Yes, I ran ts:rebuild. Yes I ran the filter as a float, but my Sphinx version doesn't allow it: "sphinxql: only >=, <=, and BETWEEN floating-point filter types are supported in this version".

Comment: Did you try bigint type? it at least is signed. Or could rewrite your filter. eg `== -1` could be rewritten as `<= 0.5`

Comment: Yes, bigint works nicely. Thanks, you can write an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `bigint` type should be useful - its the only sphinx attribute integer type that is signed.

(as found comparing floats is more complicated, because a comparison needs to implement a threadshold - because floats are inexact - sphinx doesnt do that with filters, but can be workedaround with the IF function - no idea how to put that into thinkingsphinx)